# How to load an image on react native using notepad++

Tags: react-native

I am using notepad++ and i am trying to load an image from the same directory of the app i am trying to do.

But it doesn`t work.

The whole time i get the same error:
Unable to resolve "./07-Community-Walkthrough—01@3x" from "App.js".
I tried doing it with style or without. In both i got the same error.

When i tried puting an image from the web it worked fine.

return (

```
  <Image source={require('./07-Community-Walkthrough—01@3x')} style={{width: 493, height: 310}} />

);
```

Is it possible that there should be a significent way for puting images on notepad++? is there a diffrent way to load images?

Comment: notepad++ is a text editor, so basically you won't see any images there

Comment: I do not get the relation between notepad++ and this code but if you use "./" in require, be sure that image must be in same directory with code. If it is already there, try with writing file extension. For example if image is png file then try `require('./07-Community-Walkthrough—01@3x.png')`

Comment: Thank you. I realy forgot no write png at the end. But now that i wrote it it still doesn`t work. I don't get the error. just it is stuck with the screen empty or only with the dotted sqare.